# Report Server w/ SQL 2008 R2 Express - Can't login to Manager URL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs, sql-server-express

I just installed Report Servicing addon (Advanced Services) to a local SQL Express 2008 R2 server.  I have the configuration tool and setup the proper URLs but when I connect to them I get permissions denied:

> The permissions granted to user 'DESKTOP\Eyston' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

The problem is that the machine is a Windows 7 Pro instance not on a domain so I have no idea what account I can connect to in order to setup the initial permissions for the server.  The account 'DESKTOP\Eyston' belongs to the administrator group and was the user I was logged in to install.

Is there a way to add 'DESKTOP\Eyston' the 'System Administrator' role that Reporting Services requires to connect so I can administer the Report Server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's talking about the SQL Server permissions.

You'll need to go to Security > Logins in the Management Console and go to New Logon, then add DESKTOP\Eyston as the username (with Windows authentication). Then go to Server Roles and check `sysadmin`

Comment: 'DESKTOP\Eyston' is a sysadmin on the server.  'DESKTOP\Eyston' is also 'db_owner' and 'public' on the ReportServer database.  I'm going to try and see if I can add a few roles there.  I tried to add 'RSExecRole' and it fails with 'Cannot use the special principal 'dbo'.' but that failure could be completely unrelated.  Looking up to see if I can get that fixed.

Comment: I have same problem,

Reinstall the sql server 2008 express is not fix.